# Blocked SIM card and getting asked for PUK on Lineage OS 17.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lineageos, sim-card, sim-unlocking

I installed Lineage OS 17.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S3. Everything worked just fine until I put in my SIM card. The first thing which happened after booting was getting directly asked for the PUK code although I didn't even enter a PIN at all. So I just rebooted the phone again which made it not recognize the SIM card anymore.

After that, I put my SIM card in my Samsung Galaxy S5 with stock ROM and I got the message that my SIM card is permanently blocked.

Any idea what happened there?

Comment: no clue. sounds like lineageos has tried to unlock sim for it's own but i am not aware about such "feature"?

Comment: I didn't expect that "feature" at all :D

Comment: can you reproduce with another sim card?

Comment: I was affraid to put in another working simcard so i put in an old one. It didnt even ask for a pin, just didnt recognize it where as an old iphone asked for a pin after i put it in there.

Comment: On the LineageOS web site there is no LineageOS 17.1 for Galaxy S3. Are you sure you have installed a genuine LineageOS ROM or is it just a LineageOS based customROM? In the latter you are never sure what mdifications were made by the ROM author.

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure it might be not genuine. I downloaded it from that source:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development/rom-lineageos-17-1-t4047715

Comment: that ROM is ***Status:** Alpha* for developers, not for daily drivers. find a stable ROM with no bugs, make a fresh install of stock ROM before flashing custom ROM

Comment: thanks, will do.

Answer (score 1):

You have SIM password. You enter wrong password. Then it ask for PUK code. PUK code is link with sim card.

Use sim on normal mobile. Is it ask PUK code.

You can get PUK code from customer care. You can also get it from your online register account.

Get PUK code and use it. Weather sim card work after it.

Comment: you missed the point OP *"didn't even enter a PIN at all"* - it is a LineageOS bug (inofficial test build) and will happen again as soon as SIM is inserted